# Creating and overriding Java Enum Objects at Runtime [GregTech/minecraft]

Tags: java, reflection, enums, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to work with this enum and add new materials.
Anything not already removed has hard dependencies elsewhere, even still, this is nearly at the java byte limit according to the mods author so there isn't really a lot of room to work with anyway.

GregoriousT mentioned "There is one way. Overmind hacked the Enum using Reflection to add his own stuff. No Idea how he did that and also no idea how long he takes to reply to things if you ask him."

Enum we're talking about:
http://pastebin.com/g0aJ2Qjd

So I simply ask, how would I go about this?

This is what my current attempt throws `[FML]: Variable m:1|newInstance|public java.lang.Object sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) throws java.lang.InstantiationException,java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException|false`
 before the client crashes. (Log code removed for easy reading)

Current attempt:

```
public class MaterialsNew {

public static void getGregMaterials() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
Utils.LOG_WARNING("Stepping through the process of Greg's materials.");

    Constructor<?> con = Materials.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0]; 
java.lang.reflect.Method[] methods = con.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (java.lang.reflect.Method m1 : methods) { 
    if (m1.getName().equals("acquireConstructorAccessor")) { 
        m1.setAccessible(true);
        m1.invoke(con, new Object[0]);}
} 
Field[] fields = con.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); 
Object ca = null;
for (Field f : fields) { 
    if (f.getName().equals("constructorAccessor")) {
    f.setAccessible(true); 
    ca = f.get(con); 
    } 
} 
Method m = ca.getClass().getMethod( "newInstance", new Class[] { Object[].class }); 
m.setAccessible(true);
Materials v = (Materials) m.invoke(ca, new Object[] { new Object[] { "NEWMATERIAL", Integer.MAX_VALUE } }); 
System.out.println(v.getClass() + ":" + v.name() + ":" + v.ordinal());}}
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated, they guys over at the Forge IRC weren't really sure either.

Comment: I doubt that you can do that using simple Reflection. But the question is, do you really need to hack the `enum` type or do you just need an implementation of the interfaces `IColorModulationContainer` and `ISubTagContainer`?

Comment: Besides that, you should format your source code in a readable way and stop polluting the code with logging statements between every statement. It’s very hard to read at all.

Comment: Unless it's contained within the Materials Enum, it's useless code not being loaded or even processed. Which is why modifying it at runtime is about the only real option AFAIK. Realistically though, Considering the person who did it previously is/was one of the main Forge programmers, I didn't expect this to be within my ability at all.

I know it's not a standard use case at all & it goes against the point of an enum, but sometimes you've just gotta expand on someone elses work. (I was welcomed to try so why not)

Comment: But even if you manage to create another instance somehow, `Materials.values()` still won't return it. And when you manage to hack that facility, you don't know what, e.g. `Materials.class.getEnumConstants()` will do…

Comment: Regarding you specific question, despite the single occurrence of `<?>` the entire code looks pre-Java5. So most probably, this hack worked in earlier Java versions, but doesn't anymore. JVMs are supposed to prevent sneaky `enum` instantiation and holes get closed over time.

Comment: I've got access to the source of what I'm trying to reflect, so It's not as though I'm poking into unknown classes. I just can't edit the source because then nothing else will be compatible.

I am hoping to hear back sometime from the original person who managed to do this all previously, but until then I'm still interest in what CAN be done in the meantime. I'm thinking that most things I've found which are relevant are all probably only valid for Java 5/6, but sometimes old bugs just never got patched. 

I appreciate the comments Holger and look forward to the input from anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

JVMs are supposed to prevent such sneaky `enum` instance creations. So you have to either use a flaw that soon might get solved or hack such deep into the JRE that the slightest change may break it.

Here is a trick which works with Oracle’s current JRE 8, perhaps JRE 7 as well, and is surprisingly simple:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class EnumHack {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Constructor<Thread.State> c
            = Thread.State.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, int.class);
        c.setAccessible(true);
        MethodHandle h=MethodHandles.lookup().unreflectConstructor(c);
        Thread.State state=(Thread.State)h.invokeExact("FLYING", 42);
        System.out.println("created Thread.State "+state+"("+state.ordinal()+')');
        System.out.println(EnumSet.allOf(Thread.State.class).contains(state));
    }
}
```

But don’t expect this solution to persist…